# Saving a JavaScript var into a C# Model in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to using MVC 3 ASP.NET and I have began using the Razor view engine. I am working with an API in JavaScript so I'm putting this code in my view. I am also working with a database through the entity framework and I'm passing an IEnumerable list of a simple class containing strings and ints as my model.

I am able to replace items in my model in the view, reorder my list of objected based on values and use C# model values in my JavaScript but I am unable to save a value calculated in the JavaScript back into my view and I know this is because my C# code runs on the server and JavaScript is run on the client machine.

I'm wondering what is the best way to save a value calculated in JavaScript for each item in my IEnumerable list into my C# model so I can reorder my objects based on this value for output in order in my view.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can have set of hidden inputs in your view .And then give them related names. You can set values according to the variables you have in java script. When you post your form you can get all the variable in the action using the names of the related hidden input.

Or you can post them using ajax post or using jquery to your action. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post("action/Controller",{var1:"1",var2:"2"},function(data){
  //this will execute after the post completed(after the server response)

})
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to have a client (browser) talk to your server is through HTTP.

This means you either use a `<form>` and submit it or you use ajax.

ASP.NET MVC should have solid constructs in place for handling ajax requests.

Also note it's bad practice to have JavaScript in your views, they should be external files.